# How to display GeoJSON file over OSM, with Google satellite as a base layer (at correct location) in open layer?

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, openlayers-2

How can you display a GeoJSON file over OSM, with Google satellite as a base layer (at the correct location) in OpenLayers?

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{
            projection: "EPSG:900913",
            displayProjection: "EPSG:4326",
    }); 
    layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("districts_2011census", 
                    "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/satya/wms?",
                { layers: 'districts_2011census', 
                  format: 'image/png'
                },
                { layers: 'basic' } 
            );
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets",
      { sphericalMercator: true,numZoomLevels: 20} );
      geojsonayer1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON23", {
          Projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "../geojson/result_routing.geojson",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
                }),
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh({force:true}),
 new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({ratio:2, resFactor: 3})],
                style: {
                    graphicName:'cross',
                    pointRadius: 5,
                  'strokeWidth':4,
                  'fillColor':'#ff0000',
                  'strokeColor':'#ff0000' 
                }
                });

        var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(68,8, 95, 34); 
        map.addLayers([layer,gmap,geojsonayer1]);

        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());     
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine());
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults());
        map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
```